# TYPO3 - Is it not allowed to use names in typoscript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I modified a part of a working typoscript template from:

```
10 = COA
10.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="toggleBar">|</div>
10 {
...
```

to

```
toggleBarDIV = COA
toggleBarDIV.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="toggleBar">|</div>
toggleBarDIV {
...
```

Now it is not working anymore. Is it not allowed to use names in typoscript?
Where is it allowed and where not? Where can I get more infos?

Comment: Is it everywhere allowed except for **COA** ?

Comment: Can you show more code please? What is 10 part of? If 10 is part of another COA, then you find the answer in the allowed properties of COA: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/CoaAndCoaInt/Index.html#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, COA keys must always be numbers (10,20,1,2...);

There is a feature request about using more meaningful keys:

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/45488

Comment: So it will only be possible at TYPO3 v9.